# Can Blockchain technology be really descentralized while using centralized ISP?

Tags: nodes, decentralization

There are [15 tier 1 network providers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tier_1_network). As I see it the vast majority of internet traffic passes through one of these 15 providers. Since a node has to connect to its peers through one of these profoundly centralized providers, isn't this a limitation to actual blockchain decentralization?

Answer (score 0):

It is, but at the same time nothing is stopping the formation of a decentralized ISP other than the fact that it hasn't been done yet.

Comment: That day we will have true decentralization. Until that time we are partly decentralized